# How to check if group is expanded or collapsed in Android ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm looking for an API like `isExpanded()` or `isCollapsed()` that tells me if a group is expanded or collapsed.

Comment: `isGroupExpanded (int groupPosition)` perhaps?

Answer (score 16):

You can use **`isGroupExpanded`** .

```
 expListViewObj.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                            int groupPosition, long id) {

                    if(parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
                    {

                     // Do your Staff
                    }
                    else{

                       // Expanded ,Do your Staff

                    }


                    return false;
                }
            });
```

For more details you can visit Here

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnGroupClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener)

Answer (score 2):

As [@George D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2583086/george-d) wrote there is `ExpandableListView .isGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)` method. Well you could add the code to get expanded group position or -1

```
public int getExpandedGroupPosition() {
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupCount(); i++) {
        if ( listView.isGroupExpanded(i) ) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If u use `BaseExpandableListAdapter` class you have `getGroupView()` override method.

```
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    // Here is your expand list view parent id
    // b specify that parent expand or not.

    .............

    if(b){
        imdDownArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imdUpArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        imdDownArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imdUpArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    ...............
    return view;
}
```

so using this simple code you can show arrow up or down

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter in `getGroupView()` on your `ExpandableListAdapter`, a boolean that represents wheter the group is expanded or not.

From (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupView(int, boolean, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)

> Gets a View that displays the given group. This View is only for the group--the Views for the group's children will be fetched using getChildView(int, int, boolean, View, ViewGroup)).
>
> Parameters
>
> > groupPosition the position of the group for which the View is returned
> >
> > **isExpanded  whether the group is expanded or collapsed**
> >
> > convertView   the old view to reuse, if possible. You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view. It is not guaranteed that the convertView will have been previously created by getGroupView(int, boolean, View, ViewGroup).
> >     parent  the parent that this view will eventually be attached to