# How to know whether particular group is exist in ExapndableListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

Because I want to do this:

```
expandableListView.expandGroup(4);
```

and because sometimes it not exist because I remove header based on delete by user

or tell me another ways to give pos not hardcoded 
expandableListView.expandGroup(4);

**Edit:**

```
if (expandableCategoryAdapter.getGroupCount() == 5) {
                            expandableListView.expandGroup(4);
                        }
```

Instead of 4 and 5, I want to do like it depends on adapter/list size.
How can I do that? I don't want to hardcore 4 and 5

Comment: There is a parameter in getGroupView() on your ExpandableListAdapter, a boolean that represents wheter the group is expanded or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907941/how-to-check-if-group-is-expanded-or-collapsed-in-android-expandablelistview

Comment: `getGroupCount` will return the number of group .. Also you do not call `expandGroup` with some random int it should be less than group Count .

Comment: @ADM reason: I want to expand particular group not all

Comment: @JaiminModi Please see updated question

Comment: @ADM  Please see updated question

Comment: How do you get the Group position which you want to expand ?

Comment: Simply, check with your collection size. If using ArrayList for your adapter then check using your_arraylist.size() instead of static 4 and 5.

Comment: @ADM I calculated manually and set 4 index

Comment: @JaiminModi I can't because there are 4 -5 separate list accroding to header

Comment: @KiaraSingh You need to study ExpandableListView first properly.

Comment: @JaiminModi I'm showing according to  TAg, and it is proper also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code → first you have to check how many groups does expandableListView have.

```
int groupCount = expandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupCount();
        if (x < groupCount) {
            expandableListView.expandGroup(x);
        } else {
            (your own code) }
```